# Was differential thrust used in the P-38 to improve turn performance?

Tags: military, flight-controls, aviation-history

In the P-38 Lightning could differential thrust be used to improve turn performance ? If so what was the procedure ?

Comment: I don't think this needs to be limited to the P-38, all twin engine aircraft with some distance between the wing mounted engines should exhibit the same behavior. I don't think it will though, given the dynamics of the turn force, you will be introducing significant yaw. What do you mean "turn performance"? Turn rate? or Radius?

Comment: Could it? According to what?

Comment: Ron Beyer. I meant both rate and or radius. Sorry for my imprecise language.

Answer (score 11):

According to WW2 pilots, no. Aside from the dangers in adjusting 1600hp on one side of the aircraft on the fly in the midst of a dogfight... With the P38, they didn't need to. The P38 had an inherent advantage over single engine prop fighters of its era. Its engines (and propellers) rotated in opposite directions, canceling out any torque effect. The counter rotating engines and props were considered a big secret on the P38 when it was first designed. (as if anyone couldn't look at the angle of the props on each side and tell that.)

The pronounced torque of the 1600hp-2000hp single seat fighters played a major role in aircraft handling: both in takeoff and power on maneuvers, something WW2 flight simulators never seem to reproduce. Single engine fighters would roll left far quicker than they could roll right, due to the immense torque of the engine/prop combination, aiding in the left roll but inhibiting a roll to the right. This was most evident at lower altitudes, where the air is thicker and the torque effect more pronounced.

Not so with the P38 - contra rotating engines and props canceled the torque, and the P38 could roll right far quicker than any single engine fighter. While the P38 did have several issues at high altitude, WW2/Vietnam ace Robin Olds held that nothing could beat a P38... down low. (revisit the Dogfights/Air Ambush episode for that)

So, no, they didn't use asymmetrical engine power for maneuvering with the P38 - they didn't need to. Just roll right and turn - no single engine fighter of that day could stay with you.

Comment: Interesting that this answer is diametrically opposed by [Spectre](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/65913/5517)'s new answer. Your answer was essentially "According to WWII pilots, no", while his is "According to WWII pilots, yes". I've got no clue who is right. If you have some links to back up your claim, that would give it much more weight.

Answer (score 8):

I know this question was asked years ago. But yes, differential thrust was used and was a trick up the sleeve of 38 drivers. Irv Ethel used differential thrust to escape a gaggle of 109s over Africa after his flight was jumped near Lake Bizerte in Tunisia. He taught the maneuver to other 38 pilots who then used it both offensively and defensively. The idea was to chop throttle on the side that you wanted to roll to. This could be used offensively to beat an enemy aircraft into a split-s, or could be used to rapidly reverse direction as if spinning the plane around a vertical pole. The P-38’s counter-rotating props combined with the prop’s airflow over the wings, which supplemented lift at lower speed made the Lightning capable of fantastic low airspeed and high angle-of-attack maneuvers that single-engine aircraft watched in disbelief.

Comment: To be slightly more precise, the end effect is a yaw moment, not exactly roll. A rolling moment will also be induced depending on the place the engines are mounted and the general design of the airplane. In the same spirit, the rate of yaw (which is what a pilot will be interested in) will depend on so many parameters that one can speak only for a particular class of airplanes.

Comment: @ares "..chopt the throttle on the side that you wanted to roll to." seems pretty clear, there isn't a claim being made that differential thrust causes a roll.

Comment: Interesting that this answer is diametrically opposed to [tj1000](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/40862/5517)'s answer. His answer was essentially "According to WWII pilots, no", while this one is "According to WWII pilots, yes". I've got no clue who is right. If you have some links to back up your claim, that would give it much more weight.

Comment: @FreeMan Here is Ethell's [account](https://www.sensibility.com/mission-bizerte-a-very-long-day-at-the-office-my-grandfathers-story) of the event (originally published in Flight Journal.) It is not clear whether this became a common tactic.

Comment: Subtle distinction: the question (and to some extent, the "no" answers) address sustained ***turn*** performance; this answer addresses ***roll*** rate. Related, but not identical.

Comment: With hundreds (or even thousands) of pilots over the operational life of the P-38, it is no wonder that some pilots may have found differential thrust worthwhile and used it; and other pilots finding differential thrust not worthwhile.

Comment: @Koyovis, not only I understand it as a definite claim the differential thrust causes (or rather helps) roll, but it's the only reading that makes sense! The P-38 props spin inboard up, so by retarding the inside engine you get 1. the torque of the outside engine bank you into the turn and 2. the inboard wing losing some lift also banking you into the turn. There is also yaw effect but that is not useful in a high-G turn when the wings end up nearly vertical and most of the turning is done by the elevator. But a quicker roll into the turn can make a lot of difference in aerial combat.

Comment: @RalphJ, the question does not say “sustained”, just turn performance. And for fighters how fast it can initiate the turn, that is roll into it, is often even more important than the G it can pull.

Comment: What don't I understand? "Turn" is *NOT* roll. Everything about this answer is about the effect of differential thrust on roll rate, nowhere does it explain how this would affect *turn*, which is either turn rate (change in aircraft heading per second), or turn radius (the size of the turn circle you are moving on. Neither of these can possibly be affected positively by differential thrust.  I am downvoting.

Comment: @Jan Hadek, You are right, roll rate is important, but noting that it is important does not in any way mean that turn performance is better with a higher roll rate. Put Giant Ailerons on an F-104 and it will still take the whole state of Arizona to turn around. Engine thrust, and induced drag are also *very* important on turn performance, because they affect the ability to maintain a turn rate over a sustained period of time, but again, they are not the same thing as instantaneous turn rate.

Comment: The T-38 could roll at 720 degrees per second, but a Cessna 172 has a much higher turn rate and smaller turn radius. it appears to me you are not answering the question asked, but a different one, to wit, " ...  could differential thrust be used to improve combat *maneuvering* performance ? ..."  Now that question does include the concept of roll rate, engine thrust, and sustainability, as well as other factors.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously, I am no stranger to grave digging.)

I noticed that for this question there is not a single reference in any of the existing answers and the top two directly contradict each other. While it is impossible to prove a negative (that no one ever used differential thrust in a P38 to improve handling) it is possible to look at how the aircraft was supposed to be used.

A 1943 P38 training video (essentially one long blur with narration) makes no mention of such a procedure. It does describe a means to increase maneuverability by using [partial deployment of flaps](https://youtu.be/aTrMY9x63NQ?t=634) as well as a mechanical stop for the flap control expressly designed for that purpose.

An [exhaustively referenced P38](https://military-history.fandom.com/wiki/Lockheed_P-38_Lightning) site describes the outward down rotation of the props as causing difficulty beyond that of a normal twin engine aircraft when a single engine takeoff occurs, as this exacerbates the effect of P factor. Combat pilots may make use of extreme characteristics to gain advantage, though this violent effect is not described anywhere on the site as being used in that way.

> Losing one of two engines in any twin-engine non-centerline thrust aircraft on takeoff creates sudden drag, yawing the nose toward the dead engine and rolling the wingtip down on the side of the dead engine. Normal training in flying twin-engine aircraft when losing an engine on takeoff would be to push the remaining engine to full throttle to maintain airspeed; if a pilot did that in the P-38, regardless of which engine had failed, the resulting engine torque and p-factor force produced a sudden uncontrollable yawing roll and the aircraft would flip over and hit the ground.

This was a deliberate design decision and a change from early model's inward down as it increased the aircraft's stability as a gunnery platform.

> The YPs were substantially redesigned and differed greatly in detail from the hand-built XP-38. They were lighter and included changes in engine fit, and the propeller rotation was reversed, with the blades spinning outward (away) from the cockpit at the top of their arc rather than inward as before. This improved the aircraft's stability as a gunnery platform.

Based on a different recommended means to improve maneuverability and the design choice of stability over single engine controllability, the use of differential thrust was not commonly used in flying the P38.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the 2 quotes come from the linked site?

Comment: @FreeMan Yes. The page is huge so the quotes can be used to find the relevant section.

Answer (score 2):

It depends how you want to turn I reckon. If by rudder only and if both engines are not flat out, then yeah you could up the outer engine thrust and yaw faster.

But that is an uncomfortable and slow way and generally not how it is done, usually pilots bank the aircraft, tilting the lift vector. That is a big vector and can provide much more centripetal force than the yaw scenario: the wings provide lift, and increasing the AoA a bit creates much more force.

[image]

The vertical tail is dimensioned to fly with one engine out, the wing is dimensioned to support the weight of the aircraft. Difference between engine thrust and weight is easily a factor 5, often more.

Answer (score 1):

In flight, differential thrust has only adverse affect.  The only benefit of asymmetrical thrust would be to facilitate yaw in stalled condition or during taxi.

A stalled example of using asymmetrical thrust would be facilitating a hammerhead maneuver.

Comment: Hammerhead typically involves zero-lift a.o.a., not fully stalled a o.a..

Answer (score 0):

Reading all this information on the question “ did pilots use differential trust during combat “

The answer is “ most likely not”
Although the p38 is one of the best fighter with two engines it will fly well on one and it could defend it self.

During combat you don’t like to lose speed.
Only if that energy is retained. Alt over energy.

Going slow the propeller factors (P factors  )
Is tremendous. Going slow and pulling one engine will render your plane uncontrollable for a brief moment. Loss of control is no good in battle .

Gong fast the yaw moment can be created bij rudders too. So why pulling that engine.
With rudders there is no adverse yaw. Just controlled yaw.

Going high and pull a engine is very unwise.
The plane fly true thin air, speed limits are totally different.   It can stall easily and or go transonic very quickly.  Meaning..there no place to go to un controlled flight.
At high altitude you keep the speed up to the best corner speed.

But maybe below 15000 ft pilots have used it.
low the air is thick and with some practice it could flip the plane like a snap roll or hammerhead. But please check that manual as airframe limitations are probably telling you not to.

Realise such an event is a wilde ride ..